# Add metadata to JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, metadata, metaprogramming

Is it possible to add metadata to JavaScript objects (including strings, numbers and functions)? That is,

```
double = function(a){ return a*2; };
addMetadata(double,{desc:"Returns the double of a number."});
getMetadata(double).desc;
```

How could addMetadata and getMetadata be implemented?

Comment: For objects, yes.  For strings and numbers and booleans, no. You can always create your own map structure I guess, but I wouldn't call that "metadata" unless I really wanted to for some reason :-)

Comment: Functions are objects in JavaScript, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For objects, including functions, the best way to implement get/setMetadata is not to implement it at all.

```
double = function(a){ return a*2; };
double.desc = "Returns the double of a number."
alert(double.desc);
```

For "primitive" strings/numbers you can use a dictionary approach like suggested in another answer:

```
metaStorage = {}

setMetaData = function(obj, data) {
    if(typeof obj == "object")
        obj._metaData = data;
    else
        metaStorage[obj] = data;
}

getMetaData = function(obj) {
    if(typeof obj == "object")
        return obj._metaData;
    else
        return metaStorage[obj];
}

setMetaData(1, "this is one");
console.log(getMetaData(1))


setMetaData(window, "my window");
console.log(getMetaData(window))
```

However, I can't imagine how it could be useful to attach metadata to string/number literals.

Comment: I was not aware you could use functions as objects, so that's the solution.

Comment: @Dokkat: Everything, apart from primitive values, is an object.

Comment: Btw, just FYI, you would not be able to distinguish between `1` and `"1"` or `true` and `"true"` with this method. That's a limitation of property names really (everything is converted to a string).

Comment: Also, you couldn't distinguish between identical strings that are actually different things. For example, two texts could contain an identical phrase, but you could want to tag them pointing to their respective article.

Comment: @Dokkat: in this case, these "texts" should be actually objects, not just literal strings.

Comment: @FelixKling: yes, a more realistic solution should use a nested dict and something like `storage[typeof x][x]=data`, but again, I fail to see any point in attaching data to primitives.

Comment: Regarding the reason/point of attaching data/metadata to primitives, wouldn't it be nice to be able to do something like  `myClass.myProperty.isValid`?   Knockout makes every property a function to enable this but it's a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
var metaDataStorer = {};
function addMetadata(object, meta) {
    metaDataStorer[object] = meta;
}
function getMetadata(object) {
    return metaDataStorer[object];
}
```

Comment: Object properties have to have string-valued property names (the property *values* can be anything, but the names have to be strings, in other words).

Comment: Libert, try making more than one object and console.log your metaDataStorer.